# gmake fails immediately in PASE

Tags: gcc, ibm-midrange, ghostscript, gnu-make

I'm a security officer on this iSeries, using PASE (Portable Application Security Environment -- essentially a virtual AIX-like sandbox on OS/400) to compile Ghostscript 9.05. I've downloaded and installed RPM for AIX in my PASE environment, and then used the RPMs for gcc (gcc-4.0.0-1.aix5.3.ppc) and the rest of a standard GNU dev environment to install them on PASE, as well. Configure works fine (within /QOpenSys/usr/bin/-sh, I use CALL QP2TERM to get there), but when I then attempt gmake (make defaults to cc instead of gcc here), it fails immediately with:

```
$ pwd                                                       
/QOpenSys/download/ghostscript-9.05/ghostscript-9.05      
$ gmake                                                     
Makefile:1: *** missing separator.  Stop.
```

I read the [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1326822/makefile-cant-understand-comments) on this, and purged my Makefile.in of comments and ran it through `cat -vet Makefile.in`. Results are included below; they look fine to me, but I still receive the error above. (Note that this was pulled from a 5250 emulator session; line breaks in the display do not correlate with Makefile.in line breaks, which are shown as a $ instead):

```
$ cat -vet Makefile.in                                                     
BINDIR=./$(BUILDDIRPREFIX)bin$                                             
GLSRCDIR=./base$                                                           
GLGENDIR=./$(BUILDDIRPREFIX)@OBJDIR_BSDMAKE_WORKAROUND@$                   
GLOBJDIR=./$(BUILDDIRPREFIX)@OBJDIR_BSDMAKE_WORKAROUND@$                   
AUXDIR=$(GLGENDIR)/aux$                                                    
PSSRCDIR=./psi$                                                            
PSLIBDIR=./lib$                                                            
PSRESDIR=./Resource$                                                       
PSGENDIR=./$(BUILDDIRPREFIX)@OBJDIR_BSDMAKE_WORKAROUND@$                   
PSOBJDIR=./$(BUILDDIRPREFIX)@OBJDIR_BSDMAKE_WORKAROUND@$                   
CONTRIBDIR=./contrib$                                                      
include $(GLSRCDIR)/version.mak$                                           
DD=$(GLGENDIR)/$                                                            
GLD=$(GLGENDIR)/$                                                           
PSD=$(PSGENDIR)/$                                                           
INSTALL = $(GLSRCDIR)/instcopy -c$                                          
INSTALL_PROGRAM = $(INSTALL) -m 755$                                        
INSTALL_DATA = $(INSTALL) -m 644$                                           
INSTALL_SHARED = @INSTALL_SHARED@$                                          
prefix = @prefix@$                                                          
exec_prefix = @exec_prefix@$                                                
bindir = @bindir@$                                                          
scriptdir = $(bindir)$                                                      
includedir = @includedir@$                                                  
libdir = @libdir@$                                                          
mandir = @mandir@$                                                          
man1ext = 1$                                                               
man1dir = $(mandir)/man$(man1ext)$                                         
datadir = @datadir@$                                                       
datarootdir = @datarootdir@$                                               
gsdir = @datadir@/ghostscript$                                             
gsdatadir = $(gsdir)/$(GS_DOT_VERSION)$                                    
gssharedir = @libdir@/ghostscript/$(GS_DOT_VERSION)$                       
gsincludedir = @includedir@/ghostscript/$                                  
docdir=$(gsdatadir)/doc$                                                   
exdir=$(gsdatadir)/examples$                                               
GS_DOCDIR=$(docdir)$                                                       
CUPSCFLAGS=@CUPSCFLAGS@$                                                   
CUPSLIBS=@CUPSLIBS@$                                                       
CUPSLIBDIRS=@CUPSLIBDIRS@$                                                 
CUPSSERVERBIN=@CUPSSERVERBIN@$                                               
CUPSSERVERROOT=@CUPSSERVERROOT@$                                             
CUPSDATA=@CUPSDATA@$                                                         
CUPSPDFTORASTER=@CUPSPDFTORASTER@$                                           
CUPSINSTTARGET=@CUPSINSTALL@$                                                
COMPILE_INITS=@COMPILE_INITS@$                                               
GS_LIB_DEFAULT=$(gsdatadir)/Resource/Init:$(gsdatadir)/lib:$(gsdatadir)/Resou
rce/Font:$(gsdir)/fonts:@fontpath@$                                          
GS_CACHE_DIR="~/.ghostscript/cache/"$                                        
SEARCH_HERE_FIRST=0$                                                         
GS_INIT=gs_init.ps$                                                          
GENOPT=$                                                                     
CAPOPT= @HAVE_MKSTEMP@ @HAVE_FILE64@ @HAVE_MKSTEMP64@ @HAVE_FONTCONFIG@ @HAVE
_LIBIDN@ @HAVE_SETLOCALE@ @HAVE_SSE2@ @HAVE_DBUS@ @HAVE_BSWAP32@ @HAVE_BYTESW
AP_H@$                                                                      
GS=@GS@@EXEEXT@$                                                            
DEBUGDIRPREFIX=debug$                                                       
MEMENTODIRPREFIX=mem$                                                       
PGDIRPREFIX=pg$                                                             
FT_BRIDGE=@FT_BRIDGE@$                                                      
SHARE_FT=@SHARE_FT@$                                                        
FTSRCDIR=@FTSRCDIR@$                                                        
FT_CFLAGS=@FT_CFLAGS@$                                                      
FT_LIBS=@FT_LIBS@$                                                          
FT_CONFIG_SYSTEM_ZLIB=@FT_SYS_ZLIB@$                                        
@INSERT_UFST_BRIDGE_EQUAL_ONE@$                                             
UFST_ROOT=@UFST_ROOT@$                                                      
UFST_LIB_EXT=@UFST_LIB_EXT@$                                                
UFST_ROMFS_ARGS?=-b \$                                                       
 -P $(UFST_ROOT)/fontdata/mtfonts/pcl45/mt3/ -d fontdata/mtfonts/pcl45/mt3/ p
cl___xj.fco plug__xi.fco wd____xh.fco \$                                     
 -P $(UFST_ROOT)/fontdata/mtfonts/pclps2/mt3/ -d fontdata/mtfonts/pclps2/mt3/
 pclp2_xj.fco \$                                                             
 -c -P $(PSSRCDIR)/../lib/ -d Resource/Init/ FAPIconfig-FCO$                 
UFSTROMFONTDIR=\"%rom%fontdata/\"$                                           
UFSTDISCFONTDIR?=\"$(UFST_ROOT)/fontdata/\"$                                 
UFST_CFLAGS=@UFST_CFLAGS@$                                                   
JSRCDIR=@LIBJPEGDIR@$                                                        
SHARE_JPEG=@SHARE_LIBJPEG@$                                                  
JPEG_NAME=jpeg$                                                              
SHARE_LIBPNG=@SHARE_LIBPNG@$                                                 
PNGSRCDIR=@LIBPNGDIR@$                                                       
LIBPNG_NAME=png$                                                            
SHARE_LIBTIFF=@SHARE_LIBTIFF@$                                              
TIFFSRCDIR=@LIBTIFFDIR@$                                                    
TIFFPLATFORM=unix$                                                          
TIFFCONFIG_SUFFIX=$                                                         
LIBTIFF_NAME=tiff$                                                          
SHARE_ZLIB=@SHARE_ZLIB@$                                                    
ZSRCDIR=@ZLIBDIR@$                                                          
ZLIB_NAME=z$                                                                
JBIG2_LIB=@JBIG2_DECODER@$                                                  
SHARE_JBIG2=@SHARE_JBIG2@$                                                  
JBIG2SRCDIR=@JBIG2DIR@$                                                     
JBIG2_CFLAGS=@JBIG2_AUTOCONF_CFLAGS@$                                       
JPX_LIB=@JPX_DECODER@$                                                      
SHARE_JPX=@SHARE_JPX@$                                                      
JPXSRCDIR=@JPXDIR@$                                                         
JPX_CFLAGS=@JPX_AUTOCONF_CFLAGS@$                                           
ICCSRCDIR=icclib$                                                           
SHARE_LCMS=@SHARELCMS@$                                                     
LCMSSRCDIR=@LCMSDIR@$                                                       
LCMS2SRCDIR=@LCMS2DIR@$                                                     
LCMS_CFLAGS=@LCMS_ENDIAN@$                                                  
LCMS2_CFLAGS=@LCMS2_ENDIAN@$                                                
WHICH_CMS=@WHICHLCMS@$                                                      
SHARE_IJS=@SHAREIJS@$                                                       
IJS_NAME=@IJSLIB@$                                                          
IJSSRCDIR=@IJSDIR@$                                                         
IJSEXECTYPE=unix$                                                           
SHARE_LCUPS=@SHARELCUPS@$                                                   
LCUPS_NAME=cups$                                                            
LCUPSSRCDIR=cups$                                                           
LCUPSBUILDTYPE=@LCUPSBUILDTYPE@$                                            
CUPS_CC=$(CC)$                                                              
SHARE_LCUPSI=@SHARELCUPSI@$                                                 
LCUPSI_NAME=cupsimage$                                                      
LCUPSISRCDIR=cups$                                                          
CUPS_CC=$(CC)$                                                              
AR=ar$                                                                      
ARFLAGS=qc$                                                                 
RANLIB=@RANLIB@$                                                            
CC=@CC@$                                                                    
CCAUX=@CC@$                                                                 
CCLD=$(CC)$                                                                
CCAUXLD=$(CCAUX)$                                                          
GCFLAGS=@CPPFLAGS@ @GCFLAGS@ @CFLAGS@$                                     
CFLAGS_STANDARD=@OPT_CFLAGS@$                                              
CFLAGS_DEBUG=@DBG_CFLAGS@$                                                 
CFLAGS_PROFILE=-pg @OPT_CFLAGS@$                                           
CFLAGS_SO=@DYNAMIC_CFLAGS@$                                                
AC_CFLAGS=@DYNAMIC_FLAGS@$                                                 
FONTCONFIG_CFLAGS=@FONTCONFIG_CFLAGS@$                                     
FONTCONFIG_LIBS=@FONTCONFIG_LIBS@$                                         
DBUS_CFLAGS=@DBUS_CFLAGS@$                                                 
DBUS_LIBS=@DBUS_LIBS@$                                                     
ACDEFS=@DEFS@$                                                             
CFLAGS=$(CFLAGS_STANDARD) $(GCFLAGS) $(AC_CFLAGS) $(XCFLAGS)$              
AC_LDFLAGS=@X_LDFLAGS@$                                                     
LDFLAGS=@LDFLAGS@ $(AC_LDFLAGS) $(XLDFLAGS)$                                
EXTRALIBS=$(XTRALIBS) @LIBS@ @DYNAMIC_LIBS@ @FONTCONFIG_LIBS@ @FT_LIBS@$    
STDLIBS=@PTHREAD_LIBS@ -lm$                                                 
XINCLUDE=@X_CFLAGS@$                                                        
XLIBDIRS=@X_LDFLAGS@$                                                       
XLIBDIR=$                                                                   
XLIBS=@X_LIBS@$                                                             
SYNC=@SYNC@$                                                                
RM=rm -f$                                                                   
SOC_CFLAGS^I=^I@SOC_CFLAGS@$                                                
SOC_LIBS^I=^I@SOC_LIBS@$                                                    
SOC_LOADER^I=^I@SOC_LOADER@$                                                
FEATURE_DEVS=$(PSD)psl3.dev $(PSD)pdf.dev $(PSD)dpsnext.dev $(PSD)ttfont.dev
$(PSD)epsf.dev $(GLD)pipe.dev $(GLD)gsnogc.dev $(GLD)htxlib.dev $(PSD)fapi.de
v @JBIG2DEVS@ @JPXDEVS@ @UTF8DEVS@$                                          
FEATURE_DEVS_ALL=$(PSD)psl3.dev $(PSD)pdf.dev $(PSD)dpsnext.dev $(PSD)ttfont.
dev $(PSD)rasterop.dev $(PSD)double.dev $(PSD)trapping.dev $(PSD)stocht.dev $
(GLD)pipe.dev $(GLD)gsnogc.dev $(GLD)htxlib.dev @JBIG2DEVS@ @JPXDEVS@ @UTF8DE
VS@$                                                                         
RESOURCE_LIST=Resource/CMap/ Resource/ColorSpace/ Resource/Decoding/ Resource
/Font/ Resource/ProcSet/ Resource/IdiomSet/ Resource/CIDFont/$               
BAND_LIST_STORAGE=file$                                                      
BAND_LIST_COMPRESSOR=zlib$                                                   
FILE_IMPLEMENTATION=stdio$                                                   
STDIO_IMPLEMENTATION=c$                                                      
GS_DEV_DEFAULT="x11alpha bbox"$                                              
DISPLAY_DEV=$(DD)bbox.dev$                                                   
DEVICE_DEVS=$(DISPLAY_DEV) @X11_DEVS@$                                      
DEVICE_DEVS1=@F_DEVS@$                                                      
DEVICE_DEVS2=@P_DEVS@$                                                      
DEVICE_DEVS3=@CUPS_DEVS@$                                                   
DEVICE_DEVS4=@IJS_DEVS@$                                                    
DEVICE_DEVS5=@OMNIDEVS@$                                                    
DEVICE_DEVS6=@PNG_DEVS@$                                                    
DEVICE_DEVS7=@JBIG2_DEVS@$                                                  
DEVICE_DEVS8=@SVG_DEVS@$                                                    
DEVICE_DEVS9=$                                                              
DEVICE_DEVS10=$                                                             
DEVICE_DEVS11=$                                                             
DEVICE_DEVS12=$                                                             
DEVICE_DEVS13=$                                                             
DEVICE_DEVS14=$                                                             
DEVICE_DEVS15=$                                                             
DEVICE_DEVS16=$                                                             
DEVICE_DEVS17=$                                                             
DEVICE_DEVS18=$                                                             
DEVICE_DEVS19=$                                                             
DEVICE_DEVS20=$                                                             
DEVICE_DEVS21=$                                                             
GS_SHARED_OBJS=@DYNAMIC_DEVS@$                                              
MAKEFILE=Makefile$                                                          
TOP_MAKEFILES=$(MAKEFILE) $(GLSRCDIR)/unixhead.mak$                         
AK=$                                                                        
CCFLAGS=$(GENOPT) $(CAPOPT) $(CFLAGS)$                                      
CC_=$(CC) $(CCFLAGS)$                                                       
CCAUX_=$(CCAUX) $(CFLAGS)$                                                  
CC_LEAF=$(CC_)$                                                             
CC_LEAF_PG=$(CC_)$                                                          
CC_NO_WARN=$(CC_)$                                                          
CCAUX_NO_WARN=$(CCAUX_)$                                                    
CC_SHARED=$(CC_) @DYNAMIC_CFLAGS@$                                          
LD_SET_DT_SONAME=@SET_DT_SONAME@$                                           
FOR_MAC=@SO_FOR_MAC@$                                                       
MAKEDIRS=| directories$                                                     
MAKEDIRSTOP=$                                                               
INSTALL_CONTRIB=@INSTALL_CONTRIB@$                                          
include $(GLSRCDIR)/unixhead.mak$                                           
include $(GLSRCDIR)/gs.mak$                                                 
include $(PSSRCDIR)/psromfs.mak$                                            
include $(GLSRCDIR)/lib.mak$                                                
include $(PSSRCDIR)/int.mak$                                                
include $(GLSRCDIR)/freetype.mak$                                           
include $(GLSRCDIR)/jpeg.mak$                                               
include $(GLSRCDIR)/zlib.mak$                                               
include $(GLSRCDIR)/png.mak$                                                
include $(GLSRCDIR)/tiff.mak$                                               
include $(GLSRCDIR)/jbig2.mak$                                              
include $(GLSRCDIR)/jasper.mak$                                             
include $(GLSRCDIR)/ldf_jb2.mak$                                            
include $(GLSRCDIR)/lwf_jp2.mak$                                            
include $(GLSRCDIR)/openjpeg.mak$                                           
include $(GLSRCDIR)/icclib.mak$                                             
include $(GLSRCDIR)/$(WHICH_CMS).mak$                                       
include $(GLSRCDIR)/ijs.mak$                                                
@LCUPSINCLUDE@$                                                             
@LCUPSIINCLUDE@$                                                            
include $(GLSRCDIR)/devs.mak$                                               
include $(GLSRCDIR)/contrib.mak$                                            
include $(GLSRCDIR)/unix-aux.mak$                                           
include $(GLSRCDIR)/unixlink.mak$                                           
include $(GLSRCDIR)/unix-dll.mak$                                           
include $(GLSRCDIR)/unix-end.mak$                                           
include $(GLSRCDIR)/unixinst.mak$                                           
@CONTRIBINCLUDE@$                                                           
@CUPSINCLUDE@$                                                              
distclean : clean config-clean soclean pgclean debugclean$                  
^I-$(RM_) -r $(BINDIR) $(GLOBJDIR) $(PSOBJDIR) $(AUXDIR)$                   
^I-$(RM_) -r autom4te.cache$                                                 
^I-$(RM_) config.log config.status$                                          
^I-$(RM_) Makefile$                                                          
^I@-rmdir $(BINDIR) $(GLOBJDIR) $(PSOBJDIR)$                                 
^I-$(RM_) $(TIFFSRCDIR)$(D)libtiff$(D)tif_config.h $(TIFFSRCDIR)$(D)libtiff$(
D)tiffconf.h$                                                                
debug-clean : debugclean$                                                    
memento-clean : mementoclean$                                                
maintainer-clean : distclean$                                                
^I-$(RM_) configure.ac$                                                      
^I-$(RM_) configure$                                                         
^I-$(RM_) Makefile.in$                                                       
check : default$                                                             
^I$(NO_OP)$
```

Comment: I''m guessing the problem seems to be in the generated `Makefile` and not `Makefile.in`. From the error it appears that line `1` of the `Makefile` has some unwanted characters. `Makefile.in` is generated by `automake`, later through `configure` script `Makefile` is generated. Can you post what the first few lines of the `Makefile` look likg?

Comment: The Makefile in the root directory simply references base/Makefile.in, which is the file included above.

Comment: Here's the contents of Makefile (using the same `cat -vet`)
`base/Makefile.in$`

Comment: Huh? I don't see your `Makefile`, only your `Makefile.in`...

Comment: @pipitas Makefile only has one line of content, which is `base/Makefile.in`. Makefile.in is where all the action is, Makefile is simply a reference to Makefile.in.

Comment: This `Makefile` is completely wrong then. A typically has more lines than just this. Also, even if 1 line would suffice, its syntax would be wrong with the line you quoted. `Makefile.in` usually serves as the input file, from which the `./configure` command should generate the real `Makefile`... `Makefile.in` in turn is either shipped with the source code (which is not the case for Ghostscript 9.05) or it is generated by the automake` command, using `Makefile.am` as the input file.

Comment: @pipitas Ghostscript's source .tar doesn't ship with a Makefile.am, just the Makefile.in. After ./configure, a Makefile appears which links to the base/Makefile.in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured this out. Full details and steps to reproduce are here: http://hewhocutsdown.net/blog/2012/04/25/how-to-compile-ghostscript-for-pase/

It came down to three items:

1. Using gcc 4.2.0 instead of older versions.
2. Running configure with the `–build=”powerpc-ibmaix5.3.0.0”` option.
3. Apply an AIX-specific patch to opj_malloc.h (an OpenJPEG libray), patch here: http://openjpeg.googlecode.com/issues/attachment?aid=1390001000&name=Issue_139-AIX-memalign.patch&token=fTYKtT77eCQohWNtP2epWWxP2xQ%3A1335385237594

Answer (score 0):

gmake most likely does not do any character conversion, so it just reads raw EBCDIC.

Check the CCSID on the IFS file is 819.

(My usual trick for creating an empty file is `touch -C 819 file`.  Also if at all possible compile on native AIX)

Answer (score -1):

What's the value of the environment variable BUILDDIRPREFIX?  Should it end with a '/'?

Comment: Not sure if this is valid, but `echo $BUILDDIRPREFIX` returns nothing.

Comment: The last time I did this some time ago, BUILDDIRPREFIX was 'so'.  If that doesn't help (and it might not, being an older version) perhaps you can simply download a precompiled version.  http://computer-refuge.org/classiccmp/aixpdslib/pub/ghostscript/RISC/4.3/exec/  Install it in /usr/local

Comment: I have a binary for an older version; I'm trying to utilize features only available in the 9.x code, thus the need for the compile.

I'll try `so` out tomorrow.

Comment: @BuckCalabro I explicitly set BUILDDIRPREFIX=so in the Makefile.in, no dice; same error.

Comment: I downloaded, unzipped, untar'd and ./configured 9.05.  My Makefile stops with a 'Cannot find a rule to create target' error, but it does run.  Not sure what else I can do to help; out of time to work on this.  Note: my Makefile is not a link - it's the full deal.  http://pastebin.com/VmPhURiU

Comment: @BuckCalabro I figured it out, will follow up shortly with a fully documented answer. Thank you for the assistance.